# Capybara and Select2 Version 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, jquery-select2-4

How can I fill in/select a `select2` search box (gets results via ajax) with capybara.

Using the latest `version 4` of `select2` and latest `capybara/rspec` in a rails project.

There are many examples on `SO` and elsewhere on how to use Capybara with `Select2 3.x` but not `version 4` which is a rewrite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [capybara-select-2](https://github.com/Hirurg103/capybara_select2) gem which supports version 2/3/4 of select2. It expects select2 version 4 by default. You can [configure](https://github.com/Hirurg103/capybara_select2#configuration) it for other version if you use select2 version 2 or 3

Just add the gem to the test group in your Gemfile

```
group :test do
  gem 'capybara-select-2'
end
```

Now you can use `select2` test helper in Cucumber or RSpec:

```
select2 'Buy Milk', css: '#todo'

# Search options
select2 'Buy Milk', from: 'Things to do', search: true

# Create new options
select2 'Millennials', from: 'Generations', tag: true
```

**UPDATE:**
Starting from version `0.3.0` CapybaraSelect2 detects select2 version automatically

Answer (score 5):

For 4.0, it looks like they actually simplified quite a bit. For a single select, you can just include this helper method:

```
def select2(value, **options)
  first("#select2-#{options[:from]}-container").click
  find(".select2-results__option", text: value).click
end
```

Works for me so far, but I haven't tried with more customized versions of the selector yet.

Comment: Can you give some examples on how to use this helper? I couldn't make it work :(

Comment: @FabianoArruda check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24382645/rspec-include-a-custom-helper-module-in-spec-helper-rb).

Comment: @a.barbieri I know how to include a custom method. Sorry if I wasn't clear on my question, but what I want to see is some use examples with capybara (for instance how do you call this method inside a spec example, what do you pass as value and so on). As it didn't work for me, I wonder if I'm doing something wrong in my specs.

Comment: If you open a new question I'll be happy to answer.

Answer (score 3):

For this you need to create your own support function (If you want to use it multiple times.)

I have a solution for select2 version 3.x.x . This should also work for 4 as well.

For this you need to create helper `spec/support/feature/xyz.helper.rb` and this file should look like :

```
module Feature
  module XYZHelper
    def select2(value, element_selector)
      first("##{element_selector}").find(".select2-choice").click
      find(:xpath, "//body").find(".select2-results li", text: value).click
    end
  end
end
```

And from call spec include like `include Feature::XYZHelper`. You can use it like :

```
select2("Text value here", "Id of selector")
```

Comment: Version 4 was a complete rewrite so some of the css selectors in your code no longer exist.

Comment: I just give a way to accomplish task

Comment: Appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: @RobZolkos how did you end up solving this?

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is old but most of the answers on here (and many other posts) have not worked for me with select2 versions 4 and above. I wrote my own function for it which also works for multiselects and multiple select2 inputs on the page. However, you need to wrap the select2 in a div with a particular id in order to find the correct one.

```
def select2(values, id)
    values.each do |val|
        if page.has_no_css? ".select2-dropdown"
            within(id) do 
                find('span.select2').click 
            end
        end
        within ".select2-dropdown" do
            find('li', text: val).click
        end
    end
end
```

Example of use:

```
select2([value_to_select], "id of div containing desired select2")
```

You must pass an array of values for selection, even if it is a single select. For each of those, it will open the dropdown for the desired select2 and then select the value.